# Use a 'Like' statement to find similar values in JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, optgroup

I have some JSON data. I cam trying to get similar values from it. Is there any ways to use javascript to do that? I am getting my JSON from the server. But I have a sample. I am trying to load different browser versions into their `optgroups`.

Is there a way to do that?

JSON:

```
[
{
    "browser": "Amazon Silk 3.30"
},
{
    "browser": "Amazon Silk 49.2"
},
{
    "browser": "Edge 42.11"
},
{
    "browser": "Edge 42.15"
},
{
    "browser": "Google Chrome 0.01"
},
{
    "browser": "Google Chrome 0.03"
}
]
```

HTML

```
<select id="browsers" style="max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;"></select>
```

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON(jsonBrowser, function(data) {
    data.forEach((d, i) => {
        let browser_val = d.browser.replace(/ /g, "%20");
        $('#browsers').append(`<option value=${browser_val} selected>${d.browser}</option>`);
    });
});
}
```

Result:
Right now, this code only populates by dropdown.

```
 Amazon Silk 3.30
 Amazon Silk 49.2
 Edge 42.11
 Edge 42.15
 Google Chrome 0.01
 Google Chrome 0.03
```

Result I need: I want to use `optgroups` in my dropdown to show:

```
**Amazon**:
 Amazon Silk 3.30
 Amazon Silk 49.2
**Edge**:
 Edge 42.11
 Edge 42.15
**Google**:
 Google Chrome 0.01
 Google Chrome 0.03
```

Is there a way to group them using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Sure. How do you define the group name? The string before the first space?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was planning on hardcoding those. But in theory yes, its the string before the first space

Comment: "Like" in this case just means "shares the same substring" then, so you could just get `browser_val.substring(0, browser_val.indexOf(' '))`, create an `optgroup` if one for that name doesn't exist, then go on. Sort your array first though; see [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/215552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the json ordered correctly? In the current state of your code the `optgroups` would only make sense if all similar browser appear after each other. But what if you have edge, then chrome and then edge again? In this case I would split it in 2 loops

1) loop through the `json` and push values into `new array` based on their name

2) loop through the new array and build the content

```
var example = [
{
    "browser": "Amazon Silk 3.30"
},
{
    "browser": "Amazon Silk 49.2"
},
{
    "browser": "Edge 42.11"
},
{
    "browser": "Edge 42.15"
},
{
    "browser": "Google Chrome 0.01"
},
{
    "browser": "Google Chrome 0.03"
},
{
    "browser": "Edge 42.13"
},
{
    "browser": "Amazon Silk 50"
}
]

var grouped_browsers = {
    'Edge': [],
    'Amazon': [],
    'Chrome': []
};
$.each(example, function() {
    if (this.browser.indexOf('Edge') !== -1) {
        grouped_browsers['Edge'].push(this.browser);
    } else if (this.browser.indexOf('Amazon') !== -1) {
        grouped_browsers['Amazon'].push(this.browser);
    } else if (this.browser.indexOf('Chrome') !== -1) {
        grouped_browsers['Chrome'].push(this.browser);
    } else {
        grouped_browsers['Other'].push(this.browser);
    }
});

var rendered_groups = '';
var formatted_browsers = {
    'Amazon': 'Amazon Silk',
    'Chrome': 'Google Chrome',
    'Edge': 'Edge'
};
$.each(grouped_browsers, function(key, value) {
    rendered_groups += '<optgroup label="'+formatted_browsers[key]+'">';
    $.each(value, function() {
        rendered_groups += '<option value="'+this+'">'+this+'</option>';
    });
    rendered_groups += '</optgroup>';

});
$('#browsers').html(rendered_groups);
```

I made a fiddle with a simple solution https://jsfiddle.net/rLbzs1ky/1/.

Comment: well my code works in both ways. But it can be optimized quite a bit. Maybe I will add a less complex version later considering that you know the order

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` in combination with `String.prototype.split` to create a sort of map. Something like this:

```js
const arr = [{
  "browser": "Amazon Silk 3.30"
}, {
  "browser": "Amazon Silk 49.2"
}, {
  "browser": "Edge 42.11"
}, {
  "browser": "Edge 42.15"
}, {
  "browser": "Google Chrome 0.01"
}, {
  "browser": "Google Chrome 0.03"
}];

const groupBrowser = (accum, el) => {
  const [groupName] = el.browser.split(' '); //Group by the first word in the string
  if (accum[groupName]) {
    accum[groupName].push(el.browser);
  } else {
    accum[groupName] = [el.browser];
  }
  return accum;
};

//Use the DOM API to create option elements for each group
const generateOptgroupEls = entry => {
  const [key, val] = entry;
  const optgroupEl = document.createElement('optgroup');
  optgroupEl.label = `**${key}**`;

  val.forEach(browser => {
    const optionEl = document.createElement('option');
    optionEl.value = browser;
    optionEl.text = browser;
    optgroupEl.appendChild(optionEl);
  });

  return optgroupEl;
};

//Create the select DOM el we will load up with options
const selectEl = document.createElement('select');

//Group the data
const groups = arr.reduce(groupBrowser, {});

//Create optgroup DOM elements based on group data
const optgroupEls = Object.entries(groups).map(generateOptgroupEls);

//Append the optgroups to the select el
optgroupEls.forEach(optgroupEl => {
  selectEl.appendChild(optgroupEl);
});

//Append the select el to the document
document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(selectEl);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```